# Outlook 365 and custom formula for column

Tags: email, outlook, email-headers

Have Outlook 365 and note you can use formulas for columns in the Inbox.

I was wondering if it is possible for a formula to read the email headers and show a custom value from there?  We have an appliance that scans incoming email and adds custom fields to the headers and I want to be able to quickly see some of these.

As an example, I found this formula for showing the from email address as opposed to the display name in Outlook.

```
IIf(InStr([SearchFromEmail], "@") = 0, "", Left([SearchFromEmail], InStr([SearchFromEmail], "@") - 1)+"@"+Mid([SearchFromEmail],InStr([SearchFromEmail],"@")+1))
```

Is there documentation on this functionality somewhere?

I'm not sure how to use the formulas to read the headers.  I know what I am looking for so could easily create a formula to extract the value I want if I can get the header info in the first place

thanks

jc

Answer (score 0):

Woohoo! Got it!

This post below gave me the answer I was after.  Use a custom Outlook form to specify the property I wanted (it was an x-header).

https://superuser.com/questions/762304/how-do-i-display-the-x-spam-headers-in-an-outlook-2010-mail-folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).